# How can I tell JVM to use a proxy in Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 LTS?

Tags: server, java, proxy

I want to install the elasticsearch-ingest-attachment for Zammad on Ubuntu Server (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS). This fails (*"Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out"*), probably because I'm behind a proxy.

I managed to set the proxy in various places (*/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies, /etc/environment, /etc/wgetrc, ~/.curlrc*), **but I cannot figure out how to make JVM use a proxy**. I tried to use these commands, but they failed (returning: *-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"https.proxyHost",'*):

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", 192.168.0.1);
```

In the end, I want to be able to sucessfully install ingest-attachment via:

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment
```

I found tons of Java-documentations, but they are confusing to me. I hoped, I would be able to just add JVM-proxy-settings in a file like */etc/environment*.

Best regards,

Comment: Sorry, I was inaccurate there. It is Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. I changed that.

Comment: found this (trying it now): sudo CLI_JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" ./elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment

Comment: still: Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Comment: I added --verbose to the command - and it shows me an attempt to download this file: 
https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/ingest-attachment/ingest-attachment-linux-x86_64-7.10.2.zip. It seems like this file doesn't exist, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Got a new url. This one works with wget. Still cannot use sudo CLI_JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" ./elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment. But I was able to download the file with wget and using the local file during the installation. So I solved my problem without finding out, how to actually use a proxy in JVM. Maybe CLI_JAVA_OPTS is the answer, maybe not.

Comment: Here's my workaround: 
cd ~
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/ingest-attachment/ingest-attachment-7.17.8.zip
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
sudo ./elasticsearch-plugin install file:///home/myusername/ingest-attachment-7.17.8.zip
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch